# Idiom for something like vantage point / perspective, but for point in time rather than place

Tags: idiom-requests

Vantage point is described by Merriam Webster as "a position from which something is viewed or considered".

In this definition, how literal is "position" to be taken? I have the feeling this is somewhat flexible, but I'm looking for a word that describes this concept, but specifically (and unambiguously) for a point in time.

Example:
When I finally delivered the book back to the library last week, it was already three weeks late.

Here I am considering the situation from the "position" of last week.

Comment: There are probably a lot of things that will be a near-fit. If you provide an example sentence you want your idiom to fit into, you'll probably get better answers. Or do you just want a different way of saying "last week" in your given example?

Comment: Think of time as the fourth dimension, and the difficulty disappears. I believe I have myself used the expression "vantage in time" (without the word *point,* since the Watergate hearings ruined *point in time* for my generation).

Comment: Use 'chronological perspective'.

Comment: Describing a group vantage point/perspective: "In last year's thinking..." Describing a personal change in perspective over time: "In my child's mind..."

Comment: @PatrickM I forgot to mention, but it's actually software development related; looking for a accurate but terse name.

Comment: Ah, so coming up with a straight up noun is a different thing. You want a word that can stand alone without supporting context from a sentence. I would personally shy away from idioms (and euphemisms, sarcasm, etc.) when coding. Unfortunately, [questions about naming programming classes and variables are off topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be able to help (this [meta question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/364) seems to say they'll be on-topic).

Comment: I'm not voting to close, because the question as asked is on-topic for the site. If you don't mind some reading, check out the recently redone [Java time API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html) and supporting [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html). They have very sane names for various types of time points and manipulations, in my opinion.

Comment: Just go with *timepoint*.

Comment: Ever hear of a "position paper"?  It's not a map.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried "in hindsight" or "in foresight"? They refer to a new understanding of a situation or a problem when viewed at another time.

From Merriam-Webster:

```
hindsight 
: the knowledge and understanding that you have about an
event only after it has happened
:  perception of the nature of an event after it has happened

foresight
:  the ability to see what will or might happen in the future
:  an act or the power of foreseeing :  prescience
:  provident care :  prudence <had the foresight to invest his money wisely>
:  an act of looking forward; also :  a view forward
```

Answer (score 0):

janusian is the word I believe you are looking for after the god Janus. People often focus on Janus representing contradictory ideas or states, but this god also represented a knowledge of past and future as well as the transition from one to the other.

By extension it should be fair to remark a point as being janus if it holds such a perspective.

http://www.yourdictionary.com/janusian

Answer (score 0):

You're overthinking this.  "Vantage point" does not have to refer to a physical location, nor does "position".  English is quite flexible in allowing figurative use of such terms.

You can quite properly write "From the vantage point of last week's meeting ..."